# From within a custom Maven plugin, is it possible to know if Maven was invoked with '-f'?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Maven can be invoked with a `-f` option which allows you to specify an arbitrary `pom.xml` file.

From within a custom Maven plugin mojo, is it possible to determine whether Maven was invoked this way or using the default `pom.xml` from the current working directory?

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
this.project.isInvokedWithNonDefaultPom()
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I suppose you're right: There is a much more complex problem back of this question, but I'm actually also interested in the answer from a simplistic viewpoint as well. If this leads me nowhere, I'd probably end up posting a brand new question, but I think that ought to be kept separate from this one anyway, as this could apply to other situations as well.

Comment: As it happens, I'm writing a custom plugin which is handling a complex situation to do with classpaths interacting with another framework. I'm fairly sure that it's uncharted territory, and I didn't want to ask a question that comes across as asking people to write the plugin for me; nor a question which gets closed as not constructive. I've asked a 2nd X-Y question recently, which is on a  completely different subject, but is actually inspired by the same overall problem. I sort of saw it as my job to pull those answers together to create my actual end-solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven source code related to this option are:

```
./maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/CLIManager.java
./maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli.java
```

(Look for keyword ALTERNATE_POM_FILE)

The source code can be obtained via git:

```
git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/maven.git
```

One part of the code uses following

```
if (commandLine.hasOption(CLIManager.ALTERNATE_POM_FILE))
```

Never tried this before but maybe there's a way you can do the same via plugin Mojo

Comment: This definitely looks like a useful line to take. I wonder if either of those 2 entities can be injected into a plugin via Plexus. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes ...

Comment: I've decided to accept this answer as it was the closest thing and the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Further to gerrytan's answer, there is an object called `MavenExecutionRequest` which gets populated with commandline information by `org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli`, and which **is** available inside a plugin Mojo, via `MavenSession.getRequest()`.

However, as the following code snippet from  inside `org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli` shows, the fact of being invoked with '`-f`' or not is lost, as the Pom file gets fully resolved as part of populating the `MavenExecutionRequest`.

So the answer is: No, it is not possible to know, from within a Maven plugin mojo, how the pom.xml was specified.

```
private MavenExecutionRequest populateRequest( CliRequest cliRequest )
{
    MavenExecutionRequest request = cliRequest.request;
    .....
    String alternatePomFile = null;
    if ( commandLine.hasOption( CLIManager.ALTERNATE_POM_FILE ) )
    {
        alternatePomFile = commandLine.getOptionValue( CLIManager.ALTERNATE_POM_FILE );
    }
    .....
    if ( alternatePomFile != null )
    {
        File pom = resolveFile( new File( alternatePomFile ), workingDirectory );

        request.setPom( pom );
    }
    else
    {
        File pom = modelProcessor.locatePom( baseDirectory );

        if ( pom.isFile() )
        {
            request.setPom( pom );
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

---

Version is maven-embedder 3.0.x